# OAuth for Desktop apps?

Tags: oauth

i wonder how do desktop apps without any domain names use oauth? or is it not supposed to be used this way? if so what do i use? say for tumblr they have an [authentication api](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api#authenticate) so i will have to put the username and password in the url/query string?

i am thinking of using WPF/Adobe AIR. how does something like tweetdeck work?

Comment: The desktop app doesn't need to know about OAuth, etc.  It just needs their tokens (which are in the cookies that get sent back to the client after they've logged in).  You just browse to the login page -- and wait for them to login -- once they've logged in (or if the browser automatically forwarded them through) you make a copy of the cookies the service sent back. -- Then for future requests, you just push those cookies back through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it may be possible, see googles docs on the subject:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app

Comment: Perhaps update the answer for the new version of OAuth? https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

Answer (score 22):

I've been puzzled by the same question about lack of domain or app url, but it turns out redirection is not the only possible way to complete OAuth authentication process.

I.e., when webapp requests access it provides callback url: the one user will be redirected to when process is completed. That's how webapp know that everything's done.

But you can't redirect to application on user's machine. Thus, there's another way: upon successful authentication server presents special code to the user. Then user copies this code and provides it to application.

You can see both ways described in [specification draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-12#section-3).
Also, [here's an example](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/2bbf877c4ea8b139) of this authentication flow with twitter.

Comment: +1 for an actual answer rather than simply pasting a link. [Another example, with Imgur](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2#response_type)

Answer (score 3):

For a desktop app where a user needs to authenticate himself, you will usually want to use the Authorization code flow.

The approach goes roughly like this:

1. setup a temporary webserver that listens on the loopback interface
2. present the login page to the user (either in an embedded browser control or an external browser), with the URL of your temporary webserver as `redirect_url`
3. upon successful login, the user will be redirected to your temporary webserver and you can obtain the access code from the `code` query parameter
4. Using the access code, you can obtain a token and start making requests using it
5. Shutdown the temporary webserver

Please note that you will have to allow localhost as redirect URL in your identity provider, in ordrer for this approach to work.

For further details, please take a look at [these sample apps](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/) from Google.

Comment: In this example, how do you deal with storing your API key and secret? You can obfuscate them by only adding them to the distributable, but those can still be reverse engineered.

This is a question I've been trying to answer for a few weeks now.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by reading about getting started with [OAuth](http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/). Eventually, even a desktop application will open a browser window to authenticate the user - TweetDeck and other Twitter clients do this, as you've probably noticed.

Tumblr, in your example, doesn't use OAuth but rather basic authentication that is being performed via simple HTTP web requests.

Comment: but if a desktop opens a browser window to authenticate it wont really be on a domain which is required to create an app with oauth right. i will read the link tho

Comment: It will actually be a domain that can confirm the OAuth token. To give you an example of a real-world OAuth powered service (other than Twitter), take a look at Vimeo: http://vimeo.com/api/docs/oauth

Comment: hmm, i notice that but how does my domain come into play? eg. my app will call my domain to authenticate the request or something? Sorry, i am a little confused

Answer (score 0):

Twitter doesn't want users entering their credentials into your application.  So at some point the desktop app will need to open a browser window through which Twitter can authenticate their users and return an access token representing the user.  From that point the desktop app can use the access token to represent the user in all subsequent API calls to Twitter.

Comment: Ok I understand the point of opening a browser, but if the call was made from a desktop app with no domain name, what do I enter for the domain name when registering? even if I have a domain name, what is the relation between the desktop app and the domain name? Like must the app make a request to that domain name or something?

Comment: your application will issue a call to Twitter - it is Twitter's auth mechansim which will accept the user's credentials and return a token.  Depending on Twitter's implementation, you *may* need to provide a callback URL which Twitter can use to return control to your application once the user has completed the authentication flow.  Does that help?

Comment: For a desktop application, what is this callback URL?

Comment: tepples:  Take a look at https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/ which explains the various options.

Answer (score -1):

**In a desktop environment you have another way to get the token, the browser open url itself.**

the OAuth2 server will redirect the users browser to the Redirect URL with the token as a query parameter, so if you control the browser used, you can read the the token directly from the url that the user was redirected to.

Graphical libraries like GKT+ have integrated options to create mini browsers that the user can use to authenticate, and it automatically return the token to the app, but other options are possible, like reading Firefox url for example.